# Editing wp-includes/feed.php

Tags: rss, cache, feed

I was not understanding why my RSS didn't update, after much wailing and gnashing of teeth I believe I have fixed this to a degree by editing wp-includes/feed.php.

I changed this:

```
$feed->set_cache_duration( apply_filters( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS, $url ) );
```

To this:

```
$feed->set_cache_duration( apply_filters( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', 1 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS, $url ) );
```

When it was changed the news did indeed refresh at least once and I believe I have set this to refresh once an hour. This is hard to test as an hour is a long time and sometimes there are gaps in the time that the RSS feeds themselves update.

Say for instance I want this to update in 30 minutes what would this look like? I'm looking for the proper way to enter the hours, minutes and seconds.

Thanks for any insight you may provide this seems like the last step. I'm trying to get the RSS feed in a news forum to update more frequently as users are news junkies and once every 12 hours just isn't fast enough for them to follow current events.

Comment: You did what?? **NEVER** edit any core files or a theme/plugin that you are not the author of. Have you tried debugging, disabling plugins and switching to a bundled theme to check if the problem persist?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, never edit a core file. As soon as WordPress is updated, you will lose your changes.

The part you've edited already has a mechanism in place to make the change you want without editing that file. All you need to do is add a [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters) to [`wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime) to set the lifetime in seconds:

```
function return_1800( $seconds ){
    // change the default feed cache recreation period to 30 minutes
    return 1800;
}
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', 'return_1800' );
```

Place that in your theme's `functions.php` file, or within a simple [plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Comment: Thanks Milo! I'm using that code in function.php now on my main site. I'm using disposable DEV sites to test themes & plugins. I'm editing the core to make it quick and common when testing out several themes. I don't care If I lose the edit in an update the sites only last 1-7 days. I know the 12 represents hours I'm just wondering what the format is to write the time in smaller increments.